# Is there a URL scheme for the Music app that allows me to link to a playlist?

Tags: ios, url

I have started using Launch Center Pro and I'd like to create a shortcut for a playlist on Music. Is this possible using the URL scheme of the app? If so, how?

Comment: I don’t think any exists, because Music app cannot be used to open any content files, and it does not access content from the internet.

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iTunes url and append &app=music.  it will look for the song or album on the iTunes catalog and start playing it locally:

https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/album/clair-de-lune/id319190952?i=319190960&mt=1&app=music

Note that this plays the first of nine songs in the query response this creates.